# Change section order on Hestia

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, css-grid

In the free version of the WordPress-Theme "Hestia" you are unable to change the order of the sections on the frontpage. There are some custom PHP snippets that allow you to change the order, but they are pretty complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use custom CSS code (for example with [this plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/)) and CSS Grid to change the order of the sections.

First of all you have to set the display of the main area to `grid`.

```
.home .main {
  display: grid;
}
```

Then you can change the order using `grid-row` and a number. The larger the number, the later it will be visible on the page.

```
.home .main #blog {
   grid-row: 1
}
```

The sections have the following IDs:

- clients_bar
- features
- portfolio
- pricing
- ribbon
- team
- testimonial
- about
- blog
- contact
- shop
- subscribe

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of the sections searching the filter 'hestia_section_priority', you can find the files in 'themes/hestia/inc/views/fornt-page' or in 'plugins/themeisle-companion/obfx_modules/companion-legacy/inc/hestia/inc/sections', only need to put the priority lower or higher